# Handle content of a div based on the link clicked in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a page with 2 div like this

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Deadlines</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-demos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/deadlines.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/deadlinesDB.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if (!window.device){
            onDeviceReady();
        }
    }
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="deadlineList" data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" data-quicklinks="true">
<!-- header -->
<div data-role="header" class="jqm-header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none">
    <h2>Deadlines</h2>
    <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
    <a href="addNewDeadline.html" class="jqm-search-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-icon-plus ui-btn-right">Add new</a>
</div>
<!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" class="ui-content jqm-content" >
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <!-- tab bar -->
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#all" data-ajax="false">All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#homework" data-ajax="false">Homework</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#test" data-ajax="false">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         <!-- tab bar -->
         <!-- tab content -->
            <div id="all" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
                <ul id="allList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <!--List will go here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="homework" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
                <ul id="homeworkList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">                   
                    <!--List will go here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="test" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
                <ul id="testList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <!--List will go here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
         <!-- tab content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>  


<div id="DeadlineDetail" data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" data-quicklinks="true">
<div data-role="header" class="jqm-header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none">
    <h2>Deadline Detail</h2>
    <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
    <button onClick="getFormInfo()" class="jqm-search-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-icon-check ui-btn-right">Save</button>
</div>
<!-- end head -->
<div data-role="content" id="contentAddNewDeadline" class="ui-content" data-iscroll>
    <form id="formDeadlineInfo">
        <label for="shortDescription">Short Description</label>
        <input id="shortDescription"  type="text">
        <br>
        <label for="class">Class</label>
        <select id="class" class="ui-selectmenu" >

        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="dueDate">Due Date</label>
        <input id="dueDate" type="date">
        <br>
        <label for="dueTime">Due Time</label>
        <input id="dueTime" type="time">
        <br>
        <label for="type">Type</label>
        <select id="type">
          <option value="Homework">Homework</option>
          <option value="Test">Test</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="additionalInfo">Additional Info</label>
        <input id="additionalInfo" type="text">
        <br>
        <label for="finished">Finished</label>
        <select data-role="flipswitch" id="finished" class="ui-selectmenu" >
          <option value="no" selected>no</option>
          <option value="yes">yes</option>

        </select>

    </form>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" class="jqm-footer ui-footer-fixed" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none">
    <button onClick="deleteDeadline()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-icon-delete ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-bottom">Delete</button>
</div>
<!-- end tab content -->

</div>
</body>
```

And the deadlineDB.js code

```
var id = "";
var db = null;
function onDeviceReady() {

db = window.openDatabase("HomeworkTracker3", "2.0", "HomeworkTracker3", 2000);

db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

db.transaction(getDeadlines, errorCB);
}

function populateDB(tx) {

 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deadlines (id varchar(10) primary key, description varchar(500), class varchar(50), duedate date, duetime time, type varchar(50), additionalInfo varchar(200), finished varchar(10))');
}

//to get parameters from URL 
GET = (function () {
    var get = {
        push:function (key,value){
            var cur = this[key];
            if (cur.isArray){
                this[key].push(value);
            }else {
                this[key] = [];
                this[key].push(cur);
                this[key].push(value);
            }
        }
    },
    search = document.location.search,
    decode = function (s,boo) {
        var a = decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
        return boo? a.replace(/\s+/g,''):a;
    };
    search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function (a,b,c) {
        if (get[decode(b,true)]){
            get.push(decode(b,true),decode(c));
        }else {
            get[decode(b,true)] = decode(c);
        }
    });
    return get;
})();

function getDeadlines(tx){
//alert('get deadline');
var sql = "select * from deadlines where finished = 'no' ORDER BY duedate";
tx.executeSql(sql, [] , getAllDeadlines_success);
var sql2 = "select * from deadlines where finished = 'no' and type = 'Homework' ORDER BY duedate";
tx.executeSql(sql2, [] , getHomeworkDeadlines_success);
//alert('get test deadline');
var sql3 = "select * from deadlines where finished = 'no' and type = 'Test' ORDER BY duedate";
tx.executeSql(sql3, [] , getTestDeadlines_success);
}

function getAllDeadlines_success(tx, results){

var len = results.rows.length;
//var s = "";
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    //id = allDeadline.id;
    var allDeadline = results.rows.item(i);
    var result = isLate(allDeadline.duedate, allDeadline.duetime).toString();
    if ( result == "true"){
        $('#allList').append('<li><a href="?id='+allDeadline.id+'#DeadlineDetail" data-transition = "slide" >'+ allDeadline.class +'<br>'+ allDeadline.duedate+'  '+ allDeadline.duetime+'<br>'+ allDeadline.description +'</a></li>');
    }
}
$("#allList").listview().listview('refresh');
    ////alert('before append');
}



function getHomeworkDeadlines_success(tx, results){

//alert('get homework deadlines');
var len = results.rows.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    var homeworkDeadline = results.rows.item(i);
    var result = isLate(homeworkDeadline.duedate, homeworkDeadline.duetime).toString();
    //alert('result: ' + result);
    if ( result == "true" ){
        //alert('prepend');             
        $('#homeworkList').append('<li><a href="?id='+homeworkDeadline.id+'#DeadlineDetail">'+ homeworkDeadline.class + '<br>' + homeworkDeadline.duedate+'    '+ homeworkDeadline.duetime+'<br>'+ homeworkDeadline.description +'</a></li>');
    } 

}
$("#homeworkList").listview().listview('refresh');
    ////alert('before append');
}


function getTestDeadlines_success(tx, results){

var len = results.rows.length;
//var s = "";
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    var testDeadline = results.rows.item(i);
    var result = isLate(testDeadline.duedate, testDeadline.duetime).toString();
    if ( result == "true"){
        $('#testList').append('<li><a href="?id='+testDeadline.id+'#DeadlineDetail">'+ testDeadline.class + '<br>' + testDeadline.duedate+'    '+ testDeadline.duetime+'<br>'+ testDeadline.description +'</a></li>');
    }

}
$("#testList").listview().listview('refresh');
    ////alert('before append');
}

//Compare deadline time with current time
function isLate(deadlineDate, deadlineTime){
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var date = now.getDate();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();

var parts = deadlineDate.split('-');
var time = deadlineTime.split(':');

if ( parts[0] < year ){// previous year
    return false;
} else if ( ( parts[0] == year ) && ( parts[1] < month)){ // previous month
    return false;
} else if (( parts[0] == year ) && ( parts[1] == month) && (parts[2] < date)){// previous date
    return false;
} else if (( parts[0] == year ) && ( parts[1] == month) && (parts[2] == date) && (time[0] < hour)){ // previous hour
    return false;
} else if (( parts[0] == year ) && ( parts[1] == month) && (parts[2] == date) && (time[0] == hour) && (time[1] < minute)) { // previous minute
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}   
}

function errorCB(tx, err) {
alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

function successCB(tx){
}

function getDeadlineDetail(tx){
//////alert('get deadline detail');
id = GET.id;
//////alert(id);
var sql = "select * from deadlines where id = '" + id +"'";
tx.executeSql(sql, [] , getDeadlineDetail_success);
}

function getDeadlineDetail_success(tx, results){

var len = results.rows.length;
//var s = "";
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var deadline = results.rows.item(i);
        var description = deadline.description;
        var classDeadline = deadline.class;

        var duedate = deadline.duedate;
        var duetime = deadline.duetime;
        var type = deadline.type;
        var additionalInfo = deadline.additionalInfo;
        var finished = deadline.finished;

        document.getElementById("shortDescription").value = description;
        document.getElementById("dueDate").value = duedate;
        document.getElementById("dueTime").value = duetime;
        document.getElementById("additionalInfo").value = additionalInfo;

                var selectClass = $("#class"); 
        $("#class").val(classDeadline);
        selectClass.selectmenu("refresh");

        var selectType = $("#type");
        $("#type").val(type);
        selectType.selectmenu("refresh");


        var selectFinished = $("#finished");
        $("#finished").val(finished);
        selectFinished.flipswitch("refresh");

    }

}
```

When I click on a list item in deadlineList div, it will jump to DeadlineDetail div with the id parameter. Now I want to get the id from parameter to retrieve info from db and then show it into DeadlineDetail div. 
If I write code like this :

```
div id="DeadlineDetail" data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" data-quicklinks="true">
<script>
    var id = GET.id;
    //do something next to get deadline detail 
</script>
<div data-role="header" class="jqm-header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none">
```

The id will be get on the page load, that's not what I want. I want the id will be get only when user click on a list item. So what I can do in this case ?

Comment: I posted all the codes I think which is relevant to my question. Sorry I'm still new with this stuffs. What do u need more ?

Comment: no, I said your code is too big to read :) Just post codes which you think is having trouble.